# Create trail effect js canvas

Tags: javascript

I would like to edit this game, so that the square leaves a trail:
https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/game_intro.asp

A trail like this:
https://codepen.io/depy/pen/amoXGB

I have tried with:

```
function createTrail() {
  myGamePiece = {
    x: 100, 
    y: 100,
    speed: 3,
    direction: Math.PI * 2 * Math.random()
  }
}
```

But it does not seem to work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What does "it does not seem to work"mean? Does it not show the trail? Does the trail show in the wrong place? Does the trail flicker? Is the trail the wrong shape or size? Help us to help you.

Comment: It doesn't show the trail.

Comment: Some more information?